# Getting inconsistent results when retrieving app roles assigned to an app via Graph api

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Relevant package versions:

1. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 3.1.9**
2. **Microsoft.Graph: 3.28**

I'll illustrate the inconsistencies with a few examples:

#### Retrieving the groups by using the powershell script

The script for getting the groups is provided here: [Display users and groups assigned to an Application Proxy application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/scripts/powershell-display-users-group-of-app)
.

**Unique groups returned: 157**

**Remarks:** The count of groups along with object ids corresponds to the ones I can see listed on **Azure Active Directory** blade on the **Azure Portal** so I'm using this as reference for the other approaches.

#### Getting groups via .NET core using the App Id

```
await graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals.Request().Filter($"appId eq '{appId}'").Expand("AppRoleAssignedTo");
```

**Unique groups returned: 101**

**Remarks:** I am unable to identify why certain groups aren't returned. To confirm that a permissions issue is not responsible for the discrepancy, I tried to manually retrieve the groups using the objectIds of the missing groups as below:

```
var group = await graphServiceClient.Groups[id].Request().Expand("AppRoleAssignments").GetAsync();
do
{
   assignments.AddRange(group.AppRoleAssignments.CurrentPage.ToList().Where(x => x.ResourceId.ToString().Equals(appServicePrincipalId)).ToList());
} while (group.AppRoleAssignments.NextPageRequest != null);
```

I was able to succesfully retrieve the missing groups using this approach.

---

#### Getting groups via .NET core using the Service Principal

In order to be through, I exchanged the appId approach with one that relies on the service principal as below but the results were the same as with the AppId.

```
await graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals[appServicePrincipalId].AppRoleAssignedTo.Request().GetAsync()
```

**Unique groups returned: 101**

---

#### Retrieving the groups by adapting the powershell script to .NET

```
var tx = await graphServiceClient.Groups.Request().Expand("AppRoleAssignments").GetAsync()

do
  {
    foreach (var group in tx)
    {
       do
       {
         assignments.AddRange(group.AppRoleAssignments.CurrentPage.ToList().Where(x => x.ResourceId.ToString().Equals(appServicePrincipalId)).ToList());
         if (group.AppRoleAssignments.NextPageRequest != null)
         {
           group.AppRoleAssignments = await group.AppRoleAssignments.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
         }
       } while (group.AppRoleAssignments.NextPageRequest != null);
     }
     tx = await tx.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
} while (tx.NextPageRequest != null);
```

Here the approach is to iterate over all groups and then filter those with the correct service principal id.

**Unique groups returned: 136**

Unusually enough, while I'm able to retrieve more groups using this approach, it actually fails to retrieve certain groups that are obtained via **the App Id/Service principal** approach. Aggregating both of them, leads to a commulative total of **146**

---

Due to confidentiality reasons, I unfortunately cannot reveal the specifics of the groups or their respective contents but each of the missing groups have members in them and are assigned atleast one **AppRole**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the approaches were correct, the library version was just outdated. Using **Microsoft.Graph: 4.15**, I can fetch the required groups using any of the aforementioned methods.